# Error comparing hash to hashed mysql password (output values are equal)

Tags: php, mysql, hash, string-comparison

Im trying to compare a hashed password value in a mysql database with the hashed value of an inputted password from a login form.

However, when I compare the two values it says they aren't equal. I removed the salt to simply, and then tested what the outputs were and got the same values

```
$password1 = $_POST['password'];
$hash = hash('sha256', $password1);
...connect to database, etc...
$query = "SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE username = '$username1'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($hash != $userData['password']) //incorrect password
{
    echo $hash."|".$userData['password'];
   die();
}
...other code...
```

Sample output:

7816ee6a140526f02289471d87a7c4f9602d55c38303a0ba62dcd747a1f50361| 7816ee6a140526f02289471d87a7c4f9602d55c38303a0ba62dcd747a1f50361

Any thoughts?

Comment: Strange problem you have encountered. What is the output of `var_dump($hash)` and `var_dump($userData['password'])`?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the exact same problem. `var_dump()` was telling me that I had two variables with the same properties, `string(128)`. The only way I was able to get the comparison to work was to cast the hashed values as strings:

```
$password1 = $_POST['password'];
$hash = (string)hash('sha256', $password1);
...
$userData = (string)mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($hash == $userData) {
  //This should return true.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `strcmp`. String comparisons with == or != rarely go well.

```
if(strcmp($hash, $userData['password']) != 0) {
    //this would be where the password was incorrect.
}
```

It may very well be treating it as a number for some reason and failing the comparison.

Comment: This is going to be a strange, last ditch effort, but try replacing `mysql_fetch_array($result);` with `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);`. This really shouldn't be the source of your troubles, but PHP is a many weird things.

Comment: Didn't work either. I dont understand since the outputs are showing the exact same values each time I test

Answer (score 0):

Try switching != to == and switch content. Like this

```
if($hash == $userData['password']) //incorrect password
{
    //proc login...
}
else
{
    echo $hash."|".$userData['password'];
   die();

}
```

I'm not sure why is that happening but you can be sure it will work in my case

EDIT: you did something wrong in your case. [works for me](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/47639.php)

Comment: I can't think of what else it could be. When I output the two values they are identical, tried changing the order to

Comment: I'm not sure why does it happen. Did you tried my first code?

Comment: tried your code in a separate file and it worked, then did the exact same on my login script with my hashed values and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

== is an object hashcode comparison, you need to use a strcmp function to compare string literals.

Comment: didn't work even with if(strcmp($hash, $userData['password']) == 0)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got this solved but I just wasted 30 minutes with the exact same problem. Turns out my mysql value had an extra space at the end. It was a test user I manually added to the database and somehow got an extra space when copying and pasting the hashed password.

Not sure if this applies to your situation or not but I thought I'd share anyway.